# Batch file process status

Tags: batch-file, process, status

Im trying to make the status set to true when the process is found but i keep getting an error saying '/nh is not availible at this time' Does anyone know how to fix?

```
@echo off
@color 02
@set Status=false

if ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq RobloxPlayerBeta.exe"') (
    Status=true
    echo found!
) else (
    echo Returned.
    Status=false
)

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the output of commands as variables unless you're in a `for /F` loop. However, if you only want to see if a process is running, you can just pipe the output of `tasklist` to a `find` command.

```
tasklist|find "RobloxPlayerBeta.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    set status=True
    echo found!
) else (
    set status=False
    echo Returned.
)
pause
```